# Angular routing precedence in two modules

Tags: angular

If an angular app has two modules: `AppModule` and `ProfileModule`, they can have their own routing configured.

In [this](https://angular.io/guide/router) guide, it says that the order of the routing configuration is important. For an example:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Here, the `crisis-center` path is evaluated first, and `**` path is evaluated last.

But, if `AppModule` and `ProfileModule` has their own routing configured, it is not clear how the evaluation for a certain route happens. If `AppModule` routing configuration has a `**` route in the end as in above configuration, this would match all routes which doesn't match to other routes in the `AppModule`. This would make the routing config of `ProfileModule` useless.

So, how does the precedence of routes work when there are multiple modules with their own routing configs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to those [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters):

> Each routing module augments the route configuration in the order of import. If you list AppRoutingModule first, the wildcard route will be registered before the hero routes. The wildcard route — which matches every URL — will intercept the attempt to navigate to a hero route.

So, the order is based on the order you imported the modules. In your example, you would need to import the `ProfileModule` first so the `**` route at the end of the `AppModule` route list didn't prevent any other routes from being processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens if the `ProfileModule` is a routed module, which is not imported by the `AppModule`? Following documentation page mentions about routed feature modules which should not be imported by any other module: https://angular.io/guide/module-types

Comment: It is talked about in the lazy loading section: https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration. Once the file is lazy loaded, the routes get inserted as children of the route definition where the lazy loading was specified.

Answer (score 0):

In cases of multiple modules, the wildcard route *should be* one in entire application, as if present in each module, the one module's route imported first will take precedence over entire route set of all other modules..

1. Import ModA routes

   const ModA_Route = [
       {path: 'moda', component: ModAComp},
       {path: 'moda:id', component: ModADetailComp}
        *no default route here* 
   ]
2. Import ModB routes

   const ModB_Route = [
     {path: 'modb', component: ModBComp},
     {path: 'modb:id', component: ModBDetailComp}
     *no default route here* 
   ]
3. Now the default route... This to land in the application's own welcome page or similar

If you add a default route for module, how will that differentiate from any other module's default route... The entry point for a module  (app/modA or app/modB) itself should be the default entry point for the module itself.. Anything else should be defaulted to the application's own logic